# Docker swarm issue connection refused on manage

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have set up docker swarm, installed on 2 ubuntu boxes, one centos, turned of firewalls, selinux, iptables.

Here is the guide I used: http://devopscube.com/docker-tutorial-getting-started-with-docker-swarm/

When I try and manage the swarm, I get this:

```
swarm manage token://28dc122221ee60ea44f587e0a338f638
INFO[0000] Listening for HTTP                            addr=127.0.0.1:2375 proto=tcp
ERRO[0000] Get http://10.20.7.143:2375/v1.15/info: dial tcp 10.20.7.143:2375: connection refused 
ERRO[0000] Get http://10.20.7.144:2375/v1.15/info: dial tcp 10.20.7.144:2375: connection refused 
ERRO[0000] Get http://10.20.7.146:2375/v1.15/info: dial tcp 10.20.7.146:2375: connection refused
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Are you using virtualbox or kvm to run those boxes? Are the machines able to ping each other? Where is the Manager (on the same network than agents or outside)? If you applied all the commands from the post, this definitely looks like a connectivity issue from the Manager to the Nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have missed the line about the updated swarm post. Here is the link to the post. 
http://devopscube.com/how-to-setup-and-configure-docker-swarm-cluster/
It works!

Comment: This was posted about a month after I had the issue, I'm going to trust you that it works now, as at the time swarm was early beta and probably just had issues.